# Subprocedure values will not display in output. With screenshots

Tags: vba, visual-studio

I cannot get the values in the TotalCost sub procedure to display in my output screen. It is just displaying zero for everything

[Ouput Screen. IT is supposed to show the total for the chairs and sofas plus separate tax and a grand total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUeDs.png)

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click

        Dim chairQuant, sofaQuant, chair, sofa, price, total, tax As Double
        Dim name, address, zip As String

        If Not DataOk() Then
            Dim msg As String = " Please make sure all data is entered correctly."
            MessageBox.Show(msg)
            Else
             InputData(chair, sofa, name, address, zip)
             TotalCost(price, total, tax, chairQuant, sofaQuant)
             ShowInvoice(name, address, zip, chairQuant, sofaQuant, price, tax, total)
        End If
    End Sub

    Function DataOk() As Boolean
        If (txtName.Text = "") Or (txtAddress.Text = "") Or (txtCity.Text = "") Or
            (Not IsNumeric(txtChairs.Text)) Or (Not IsNumeric(txtSofas.Text)) Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function

    Sub InputData(ByRef chairQuant As Double, ByRef sofaQuant As Double, ByRef name As String,
                  ByRef address As String, ByRef Zip As String)

        chairQuant = CDbl(txtChairs.Text)
        sofaQuant = CDbl(txtSofas.Text)
        name = txtName.Text
        address = txtAddress.Text
        Zip = txtCity.Text

    End Sub

    Sub TotalCost(ByRef price As Double, ByRef total As Double, ByRef tax As Double, chairQuant As Double,
               sofaQuant As Double)
        Dim chair As Double = (chairQuant) * (350)
        Dim sofa As Double = (sofaQuant) * (925)

        price = (chair + sofa)
        tax = (chair + sofa) * (0.05)
        total = (chair + sofa) * (1.05)
    End Sub
    Sub ShowInvoice(name As String, address As String, zip As String,
                 chairQuant As Double, sofaQuant As Double, price As Double,
                 tax As Double, total As Double)

        lstOutput.Items.Clear()
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Name: " & name)
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Address: " & address)
        lstOutput.Items.Add("City: " & zip)
        lstOutput.Items.Add(" ")
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Number of chairs: " & txtChairs.Text)
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Number of sofas: " & txtSofas.Text)
        lstOutput.Items.Add(" ")
        lstOutput.Items.Add(" Price: " & price.ToString("C2"))
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Sales Tax: " & tax.ToString("C2"))
        lstOutput.Items.Add(" ")
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Total Price: " & total.ToString("C2"))

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of chairQuant and sofaQuant are never initialized after they are declared. They are merely passed in to the TotalCost function as their default of 0. You need to set them to whatever they should be prior to passing them in to this function. Perhaps they should be passed ByRef to the InputData method, so that they can be intialized?

Comment: WOW! Thanks man. I completely looked over that. If I had more rep, I would upvote but thank you so much!